# Let user choose size of array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I need to let the user enter an integer N which will become the size of the array. I tired the following:

```
int N;

printf("Please enter size of array\n");
scanf("%d", &N);

int a[N] = {0};
```

However i get the following error when I do this:

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

Anyone know how can do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: change this: int a[N] = {0}; to this: int a[N]; memset( a,0x00, N*sizeof(int) );

Comment: @user3629249 simpler would be `memset(&a, 0, sizeof a);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a dynamically allocated array.

```
int N;

printf("Please enter size of array\n");
scanf("%d", &N);

int *a = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

Then you can access it like a normal array.

Edit: in C99 the compiler allows dynamic length arrays, so you can just use memset or do a for loop going through the array and setting the value for each index

Comment: He doesn't actually *need* to use a dynamically allocted array. C99 allowes and defines the use of [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and since the compiler doesn't complain about the vla it seems to be operating at at least C99 levels. Additionally your answer doesn't address the problem of initializing the array.

Comment: You can simply replace malloc with calloc to initialize the array to zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You may not initialize variable length arrays.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
>   unknown size or a complete object type that **is not a variable length
>   array type**.

So write simply

```
int a[N];
```

instead of

```
int a[N] = {0};
```

If you need to initialize the array with zeroes then you can use standard function `memset` declared in header `<string.h>`

```
#include <string.h>

//...

memset( a, 0, sizeof( a ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error says: you may not initialize a variable sized object (like that). You need to either set the individual elements in a loop, or use [`memset`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html):

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++){
    a[i] = 0;
}
```

or:

```
memset(a, 0, sizeof a);
```

Note that `memset` requires you to include `<string.h>`

**EDIT**: `sizeof a` is shorter and looks better :)

Comment: @Deduplicator I've been using `malloc` too much lately, edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int N;

printf("Please enter size of array\n");

scanf("%d", &N);

int a[N];

a[0] = 0;
```